# parse error trying to install apps on my phone

Tags: android, eclipse, parsing

I'm having issues trying to put my own apps on my phone. I've looked around and no one has been able to help me so far. A bit of background information, I'm using the latest version of eclipse IDE, trying to get apps onto my galaxy s. I tried installing apps through gmail. When I go to install the app I get a parse error and it doesn't install. I have also tried using this method to install my app onto a htc wildfire s however I get the same issue. Is there a quick fix for this? Thanks for your time; any insight into what the problem is will be great.

Things I've tried: Ok I still have a parse error when I try installing my app. The min sdkversion was set to 9 which seems right to me as that is the api level for gingerbread which galaxy s uses (i think). I haven't set a target sdkversion yet as according to the android developer guide it if not stated it defaults to the minsdkversion. I also tried setting the minsdkversion to 1 and still no luck. Any ideas?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="org.guitartunergreatness.jj"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="7" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:debuggable="true">
    <activity
        android:name=".GuitarTunerActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Not really a programming question... But what's the error you get?

Comment: Post your manifest. Also have you tried installing it via the adb, or any ways other than email? If not try with adb, or try manually copying the apk file to the sdcard and then launching the installer by selecting it in a file browser app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse error usually occurs if your app supports a higher version of Android than the version of OS on your phone. Egs: your phone has 2.1 and application supports 2.2 onwards

Comment: ok I think my main problem is understanding what the versionname and sdkversion numbers need to be. I've tried to set them to what the api levels are for gingerbread as that is what i assume galaxy s uses, but this doesn't seem to work

Comment: What is yor project build target? May be galaxy s is using froyo(2.2)?

Comment: sorry where do i find the project build target? also would i put 2.2 as the versionname or sdkversion? or neither? That's what I'm confused on, thanks for your time

Comment: What is the os on ur phone? (go to settings>About phone>Android version) To get the build target: Right click on the project>select properties>select android>

Comment: ok my firmware version is 2.1-update1 and build number is eclair, my android version is 4.0.3 so this is problem no doubt. how do i change the android version to match my phone's?

Comment: Go to project properties>Select android>change the build target to 2.1, you will have to make corresponding changes in manifest also: min sdk version. Hope you have the older targets downloaded!

Comment: ok just downloading 2.1 now, thanks for all the help, what do I need to change the min sdk version to? 2.1?

Comment: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" /> I think 7 is the one for 2.1 --Accept the answer if the conversation was helpful..

Comment: ok still have the error, please see my android manifest at the top if there is an error i have put in code. the android version is now set to 2.1 so that's not the issue

Comment: So you have changed the target to 2.1? Can you post the latest manifest?

Comment: yeah that's now changed, latest manifest is above at the start of the question, i edited it and put that in the question asked

Comment: You are able to run it in emulator?

Comment: yep that's fine, i was thinking maybe i should try installing the other platforms like 2.0 and 2.0.1 but i'm not sure if that is the issue as the firmware version definitely says 2.1-update1. i also have another phone i can try installing it on so i will give that a go and see what ahppens

Comment: wots the OS version of 2nd phone?....in Galaxy s go to settings>application> have u enabled an option like 'Allow installation of non-market application'